# AFNetworking + progress view + performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, afnetworking

In my app users can download large files (1GB+). I have own progress view to indicate downloading progress. And I'm using `AFNetworking` like this

```
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead){
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
                double progress = (double)(size + totalBytesRead) / (size + totalBytesExpectedToRead);
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ETBDownloadManagerProgressNotification object:component userInfo:@{ ETBDownloadProgressKey : [NSNumber numberWithDouble:progress], ETBDownloadExpectedSizeKey : [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(size + totalBytesExpectedToRead)*1.0/1024.0/1024.0] }];
        }];
```

I have a problem with performance while downloading files. At the same time it's possible to download only one file. Time Profiler shows that I update UI and call `drawRect:` very often. So here's my progress view setProgress:

```
- (void)setProgress:(double)progress
{
    _progress = progress;
    if (_progress > 1)
        _progress = 1;
    self.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f%%", 100*self.progress];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

And progress view drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [bezierPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2)
                          radius:rect.size.width/2 - kLineWidth/2 - kPadding
                      startAngle:0
                        endAngle:2*M_PI
                       clockwise:YES];

    bezierPath.lineWidth = kLineWidth;
    [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:.3] setStroke];
    [bezierPath stroke];

    bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [bezierPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2)
                          radius:(rect.size.width/2 - kLineWidth - kPadding)/2
                      startAngle:startAngle
                        endAngle:(endAngle - startAngle) * self.progress + startAngle
                       clockwise:YES];

    bezierPath.lineWidth = rect.size.width/2 - kLineWidth - kPadding;
    [[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:.3] setStroke];
    [bezierPath stroke];
}
```

The question is how to avoid lagging? The only way I found is to decrease number of `postNotification` for updating UI. But how? I tried to use condition like `if (i++%3 == 0)` inside `setDownloadProgressBlock`, but it's ugly :)
I also tried to replace `self.textLabel.text = ...` to `drawRect:`, but it made no sense.
Maybe it's possible to set the size of downloading pack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the i++%3 == 0 might be ugly but isn't so bad, what I would do is more something like

```
// outside of the loop
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];

__block double progressTmp = 0;
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long  long totalBytesExpectedToRead){
    double progress = (double)(size + totalBytesRead) / (size + totalBytesExpectedToRead);

    // if there was a significant change in progress ratio
    if ((progress - progressTmp) > 0.05) { 
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ETBDownloadManagerProgressNotification object:component userInfo:@{ ETBDownloadProgressKey : [NSNumber numberWithDouble:progress], ETBDownloadExpectedSizeKey : [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(size + totalBytesExpectedToRead)*1.0/1024.0/1024.0] }];
        progressTmp = progress;
    }
}];
```

The 0.05 might have to be changed to something more corresponding to your needs.

Comment: Not bad, you changed my condition to pretty one, thanks